# Разбить текст строку в php с html тегами в массив

Tags: php, html, массивы, парсер

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть строка с рандомными html тегами.
Задача разбить строчку на массив по тегам. Пример:

```
$aaa = '<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>
zzzzz zz z zz <a href="#">VVV</a> zzzzz
</p>';
```

print_r($aaa);

```
[0] =>
NAME => h1,
TEXT => Hello,
[1] =>
NAME => p,
TEXT => zzzzz zz z zz <a href="#">VVV</a> zzzzz,
```

**Обновление**

Доработал код:

```
 foreach($iterator as $node) {
     if ($node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE && ($node->nodeName !== 'html' && $node->nodeName !== 'body')) {
       $name = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $node->nodeName);
       $text = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", trim(getInnerHTML($node), PHP_EOL));
         array_push($output, array(
             'NAME' => $name,
             'TEXT' => $text));
     }
}
```

Но на выходе все равно кракозябры.

Comment: domDocument вам в помощь

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть вот такое решение:

**Исходные данные:**

```
$content = '<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>
zzzzz zz z zz <a href="#">VVV</a> zzzzz
</p>';
```

**Классы:**

```
function getInnerHTML(\DOMNode $element)
{
    $innerHTML = '';
    $children  = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($children as $child)
    {
        $innerHTML .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
    }
    return $innerHTML;
}
```

[RecursiveDOMIterator](https://github.com/salathe/spl-examples/wiki/RecursiveDOMIterator#class-code)

**Использование:**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$output = array();

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDOMIterator($dom),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($iterator as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE && ($node->nodeName !== 'html' && $node->nodeName !== 'body')) {
        array_push($output, array(
            'NAME' => $node->nodeName,
            'TEXT' => trim(getInnerHTML($node), PHP_EOL)));
    }
}
```

**Результат:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => h1
            [TEXT] => Hello
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => p
            [TEXT] => zzzzz zz z zz <a href="#">VVV</a> zzzzz
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => a
            [TEXT] => VVV
        )

)
```

**UPD**:

```
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

**UPD2**:

```
function getAttributes(\DOMNode $element)
{
    $attributes = array();
    foreach ($element->attributes as $attribute) {
        $attributes[$attribute->nodeName] = $attribute->nodeValue;
    }
    return $attributes;
}
```

Тогда вызов чуть измениться:

```
foreach($iterator as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE && ($node->nodeName !== 'html' && $node->nodeName !== 'body')) {
        array_push($output, array(
            'NAME' => $node->nodeName,
            'TEXT' => trim(getInnerHTML($node), PHP_EOL),
            'ATTR' => getAttributes($node)));
    }
}
```

В новом элемент `ATTR` будет с массивами вида имя атрибута => значение атрибута.

А рекурсивно не нужно в данном случае -- есть итератор.

**UPD3**:

```
function walk($output, \DOMNode $node, $depth = 0)
{
    if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        $children = $node->childNodes;
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            if ($child->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE) {
                continue;
            }
            $output[] = $child->nodeName;
            $item = walk([], $child, $depth + 1);
            if (!empty($item)) {
                $output[] = $item;
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}


$root = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
$output = walk([], $root, 0);
```

Вот так можно рекурсивно обойти.

**Результат**:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "h1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "p"
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
  }
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, как быть с русским языком?

Comment: @tsx, посмотрите апдейт

Comment: Спасибо, подскажите, если я хочу еще раздробить вложенные теги, каким образом мне это сделать?

Comment: рекурсивно, и записать src и href элементов (img и a) в ключ URL

Comment: @tsx, см. UPD2...

Comment: Отлично, уточните, пожалуйста насчет итератора, как мне отловить, что в тегах есть вложенность других тегов и внутри разбить на доп массивы?

Comment: @tsx, например [так](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.haschildnodes.php)

Comment: подскажите, не разобрался как развернуть всю вложенность тегов в строке - пример <p> aaa <p> sss <p>xxx </p> </p> </p>

Comment: @tsx, см. UPD3...

Comment: $dom->getElementsByTagName('body'); возвращает DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 1 )

Comment: @tsx, там `$dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0];`

Comment: так вообще ничего не выводилось, решил проверить без [0]

Comment: а здесь точно нет ошибки ? walk([], $root, 0)  в первом параметре []

Comment: @tsx, а какая у вас версия PHP, можно попробовать заменить `[]` на `array()`

Comment: жалуется на  $root = $dom->getElementsByTagName('html')['0']; - syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: @tsx, думаю, нужен новый вопрос с описанием всех деталей (на всякий случай попробуйте `$root = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*')[0];`

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501838/domdocument-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE-html-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC