# DOMDocument рекурсивный проход по html тегам

Tags: php, html, массивы, парсер

Функция для обхода по дереву

```
function walk($output, \DOMNode $node, $depth = 0)
 {
     if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
         $children = $node->childNodes;
         foreach ($children as $child) {
             if ($child->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE) {
                 continue;
             }
             $output[] = $child->nodeName;
             $item = walk(array(), $child, $depth + 1);
             if (!empty($item)) {
                 $output[] = $item;
             }
         }
     }
     return $output;
 }
```

Создаю объект

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument;
 $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

Получаю данные

```
 $root = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
 $output = walk(array(), $root, 0);
```

Но на выходе ошибка

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['
```

в строке

```
 $root = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
```

Comment: `$dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);`

Comment: все заработало, спасибо!

Comment: @splash58 в следующий раз публикуйте сразу ответом )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный синтаксис, ответ.

```
$root = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
```