# Разбить строку с html тегами в массив php

Tags: php, html, массивы, парсер, теги

Здравствуйте. 
У меня есть строка с html тегами таблицы. 
Задача разбить строчку на массив по тегам с их содержимым. Пример:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Текст ячейки №1</td>
          <td>Текст ячейки №2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Нашёл решение по ссылке [a link](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501838/domdocument-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE-html-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC/790388#790388):

```
function walk($output, \DOMNode $node, $depth = 0)
 {
      if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
         $children = $node->childNodes;
         foreach ($children as $child) {
             if ($child->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE) {
                 continue;
             }

         $output[] = $child->nodeName;
         $item = walk(array(), $child, $depth + 1);
         if (!empty($item)) {
             $output[] = $item;
         }
     }
 }
 return $output;
 }

 $dom = new DOMDocument;
 $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));

$root = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

$output = walk(array(), $root, 0);
```

Всё работает, как нужно и выводит только теги в следующем формате:

```
["table",["tr",["td",["table",["tr",["td","td"] ...
```

Вопрос заключается в выводе содержимого(не атрибутов) этих тегов.
Типа:

```
["table":"",["tr":"",["td":"",["table":"",["tr":"",["td":"Текст ячейки №1","td":"Текст ячейки №2"] ...
```

Пробовал:

```
array_push($output, array(
        $child->nodeName => $child->textContent));
```

на выходе:

```
["table":"Текст ячейки №1Текст ячейки №2 ...
```

Comment: если вам нужен текст ячеек, то и вписывайте его, когда имя тэга = `td` а не все подряд

Comment: и что это вообще за помесь json и пхп массивов в жалемом результате?

Comment: это необходимо для последующей замены содержимого других ячеек, т.е. из ячеек 2-й таблицы буду переносить содержимое в первую, поэтому нужна структура.

Answer (score 0):

решил так:

```
function walk($output, \DOMNode $node, $depth = 0)
{
 if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
     $children = $node->childNodes;
     foreach ($children as $child) {
         if ($child->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE) {
            $output[] = $child->textContent; // заменил тело в условии
         }

         $output[] = $child->nodeName;
         $item = walk(array(), $child, $depth + 1);
         if (!empty($item)) {
             $output[] = $item;
         }
     }
 }
 return $output;
}

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));

$root = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

$output = walk(array(), $root, 0);



$name = html_entity_decode(str_replace('\u','&#x',$output[1][1][1][1][1][1][0]), ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8'); // для декодирования json формата кириллицы типа - \u041d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440
```